# PHP formatting multiple currency from minor unit

Tags: php, number-formatting, numberformatter

I am current storing item prices in minor unit in the database to easily handle multiple currency eg 1500 for $15.00.

I tried using php `numberFormatter` but it seems to not support minor unit and only major unit, when I parse 1500 into the `formatCurrency` I get $1,500 instead of $15.00.

Would it be something that is out of `numberFormatter` scope and require some other library to handle?

Comment: you will need to know when to divide by 100, but not all currencies do that. Yen for example.

Comment: As @IdontDownVote said. `number_format` just adds commas etc. *You* need to organise it into the valid number, eg divide by 100 to do a straight cents to dollars conversion or by `factor` to to convert to AUD or GBP etc. *Then* you can put it through `number_format` to look pretty.

Comment: At the moment in the database I have the currency and the price in cents. say 1500 AUD. I support wide ranges of currency so I was looking at something that can parse the price in cents and currency and output the proper format. I thought `numberFormatter` would be able to handle minor units and converts it automatically to the format but I just found out I was wrong.

I found other repo like moneyphp and money but they seems too much functionality when I only want to format the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
$yourvalue = 1500;
$yourcurrency = $yourvalue / $currencyUnitValue;
echo $currencySymbol' '.number_format($yourcurrency, 2);
```

eg:

```
$yourvalue = 1500;
$currencyUnitValue = 100;
$currencysymbol = '$'; 
$yourcurrency = $yourvalue / $currencyUnitValue;
echo $currencySymbol' '.number_format($yourcurrency, 2); // returns $ 15.00
```

That´s a quick solution for your problem. I guess there are more inteligent answers.

Comment: except not all currencies use "$" or have a decimal value.